# How to handle org.netbeans.* references when migrating from NetBeans to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, layout-manager

There are a number of SO threads about importing a NetBeans project into Eclipse.  I have managed to do this, but one issue I haven't seen addressed has to do with NetBeans layout managers.  Throughout the auto-generated NetBeans code are references such as:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
```

What can be done to make these libraries available to Eclipse?  Also, do these libraries get incorporated into the build package, or are they expected to be found on the runtime platform?

Comment: They're packed into the build. NetBeans applications don't require entire NetBeans platform to be installed.

Comment: I'm a new convert to Maven, however I would recommend using it in your projects. It makes portability of code from one environment to the next a complete breeze!

Answer (score 1):

I've added to my Eclipse project's build path `org-netbeans-modules-swingapp.jar` as well as `C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.5.1\java2\sources\org\netbeans\lib\awtextra` (your path will vary) with good success.

Comment: I was able to locate both the .jar file and the directory you mentioned on my MacOS, but can't figure out how to add them to my project's build path: **Project > Properties > Java Build Path** takes me to a four-tabbed window (Source, Projects, Library, and Order and Export), and I assume I should use Library, but it's not clear to me which of the several options to take.  Am I getting warm, at least?  :)

Comment: @Chap, you could add external jars in **Library** tab, use **add external jars**. If your application is an OSGi based application, it only resolves compiling error. You would still get ClassNotFoundException in runtime. The correct way is copied that jars to your bundle, add it in its classpath, then export its packages if they're used by other bundles.